# Replace next occurrence of a string in UNIX

Tags: unix

I am new to UNIX. How to replace the next word of “the” to “there”?

I know `s/\<the\>/there/` can replace the first occurrence of "the" in the line. Text book says: `n – search forward for the next occurrence of the text searched previously.`

But where to put the "n"?

Comment: Looks like instructions for the **vi** editor.  Simply typing n followed by enter will take the cursor to the next matching word.

Comment: @ArifBurhan Do you mean I typed n first, and then typed in s/\<the\>/there/ ? It does not work as I expected.

Comment: @ArifBurhan I tried n followed by enter several times. It will take the cursor to the next matching word, but it will not replace.

Answer (score 0):

Put the number at the end, where you would expect the `g`:

```
echo "This is the test of replacing the third word the by there" | sed 's/\<the\>/there/3'
This is the test of replacing the third word there by there
```

Comment: When I typed in echo "This is the test of replacing the third word the by there" | sed 's/\<the\>/there/3' I got E518: Unknown option: 's/\<the\>/there/3'. If I typed  's/\<the\>/there/n', it still doesn't work.

Comment: With putty you get a connection to a unix server. It depends on the software on that server what commands in `sed` are supported. Perhaps you have a wrong `sed` version. My `sed --version` gives `GNU sed version 4.1.5`. I think you will have another `sed` version.